# Plot large textual graph in Rr

Tags: r, networking, igraph

I have a large incidence matrix and I need to plot the network with number of vertices between 300 and 500. I tried with igraph but i can't set the graphics parametrers. I post the code i used but the df is too big to post here. I'd like plot only the label over a certain degree threshold and a simplify the network

```
Degree=sna::degree(df, gmode = "graph", rescale=FALSE)
net=graph_from_incidence_matrix(out)
plot(net, vertex.size=0,edge.arrow.size=0, vertex.label.cex=ifelse(Degree> quantile(Degree, probs = c(0.90)), 0.5, 0))
```

Comment: What have you tried? Can you post code and sample data? Please edit **the question** with the code you ran and the output of `dput(df)`. Or, if it is too big with the output of `dput(head(df, 20))`. (`df` is the name of your dataset.)

Comment: I'm sorry but the df is to big

Comment: There is the second option in my comment, to paste the output of `dput(head(df, 20))`. This will output the 20 first rows only. How many columns does your df has?

Comment: the df has 382 colums

Comment: type `?dput()` in your `Rstudio` console, which will tell how to use it.